# How to automatically inject JavaScript into web pages such that its variables can be accessed from the developer console

Tags: javascript, browser, google-chrome-extension, inject

I have a library of JavaScript functions that I want to be able to access from the developer console of a web browser. I want to be able to run my functions side-by-side with the functions and variables defined by the webpage.

One solution I see is simply copy/paste'ing the code directly into the browser console and then using it, but it would be better if there were a more elegant solution, especially because my codebase could grow a lot and I don't want to have to copy/paste every time I load.

Another solution I looked into was using Chrome Extensions. Chrome Extension Content Scripts (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#host-page-communication) allow JavaScript code to automatically run on visits to webpages, however the above webpage states that

"*[Content scripts cannot] use variables or functions defined by web pages or by other content scripts.*"

Is there any other way of accomplishing this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Maybe something like [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=de)

Comment: tampermonkey or greasemonkey work well. i would make a simple userscript that injects a remote script tag, and edit the code in that remote url for easy maintenance.

Comment: I'm looking into this right now, and I think it's what I want. I may end up using the source (https://code.google.com/p/tampermonkey/source/browse/trunk/build_sys/manifest.json.google.com) to figure out how it works and replicate it instead.

Comment: You could make a chrome favourite that executes the javascript:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872679/function-as-google-chrome-bookmark

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE (7/7/2013):
I was updating to Firefox v22 and found out that on this latest version (or the last few versions as well... I'm not sure) the built-in Web Developer tool has a Javascript Scratchpad (press `Shift + F4` to pull it up) that will let you type in some code or, in your case, load a JS file and run it on a loaded page.

I haven't tested it extensively but I added a couple of variables to an existing page and they were both accessible via the built-in console as well as Firebug's console.  Just do `File > Open File` to open your JS file and then do `Execute > Run`.

---

One option is to create a bookmarklet (reusable and can be injected into any page) but it works only for the simplest script.  See: [here](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/javascript-bookmarklet-basics/)

Answer (score -4):

Once your page is loaded in a browser, all the javascript functions would be under the "window" object.
Like if you have,

```
function mytestfunciton() {
  console.log('This is a test');
}
```

On your console window just try these

```
window.mytestfunciton();
//and get the response below
This is a test
```

You can also wrap them in a global variable something like

```
var myapp = {};
myapp.add = function(a,b) {
            myapp.sumvalue = a + b;
                            console.log('Sum Value:'+myapp.sumvalue);
        };
myapp.substract = function (a,b) {
            myapp.differencevalue = a - b; 
                            console.log('Difference Value:'+myapp.differencevalue);
          };
```

All your functions are now wrapped under the global variable myapp and you can now invoke them from the console using something like

```
myapp.add(5,4);
```

or as before using the global "window" object

```
window.myapp.add(5,4);
```

Comment: This answer doesn't take into account the isolation between content scripts and the page's `window` object that the question quotes.