# Function as Google Chrome bookmark

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, bookmarks

Let me first say the problem I have:
I need to fill in the same web page a lot of times, and the content that I need to fill in is for the biggest part the same, but is scattered all over the webpage.

The solution i was thinking of:
I know there is a way to create some javascript function that you put behind a google bookmark so that when you are on the page, you just click that bookmark, and it will do some things.

I was wondering if anyone used (or created) something like this.
If you can make this yourself, how do you start with it? And can you use jquery?

If it's possible to create this, I was also wondering if it would be possible to, when you click, show a pop-up to ask a few parameters, so that I don't need to fill in the same thing 3,4 times

Answer (score 172, accepted):

You can do this using a [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet). A bookmarklet is a bookmark with a URI starting with the pseudo-protocol `javascript:` followed by URI-encoded JavaScript code. When you trigger the bookmark, browser will run the code in the context of the current page. So you'd go to that page, then use that bookmarklet to fill in your standard information, and there you go.

For example, here's a bookmarklet that, when run, will look for an element with the `id` `someElement` on the page and, if found, assign `"some value"` to its `value` property:

```
javascript:(function(){var d=document,e=d.getElementById("someElement");e.value="some value";})();
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for :)
Now that I know the name, I can look up if it allows jquery or not

EDIT: it allows jquery (http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/05/23/make-your-own-bookmarklets-with-jquery/)

Is there anyone who knows if it would be possible to make a popup that asks for a certain parameter?

Comment: @Brentg: Yeah, sometimes you just need to know what something is called. You *can* use jQuery in bookmarklets, but it's not generally a good idea, because you can introduce problems with the page. You have to check to see if jQuery is already loaded, load it if not, trigger `noConflict` once it's loaded in case the page uses Prototype or MooTools or something else relying on `$` as a global symbol, and at that point the bookmarklet is getting pretty thoroughly out of hand... :-)

Comment: @Brentg: Of course, for a bookmarklet that's intended for use on a specific page, if you know the page has jQuery, you're totally free to use it. Your code runs exactly as though it were in a `script` tag on the page, so...

Comment: @Brentg: *"Is there anyone who knows if it would be possible to make a popup that asks for a certain parameter?"* There's always `prompt`. Or of course, add a `div` to the page with absolute positioning, or even use jQuery UI if the page has it loaded.

Comment: Yes I can try that, but a pop-up would be a little bit cleaner. I will try to figure it and post results here :) big thanks!

Comment: Is it work in Chrome mobile?

Comment: @AralRoca - I don't know, have you tried it?

Comment: yes, only in Chrome desktop works

Comment: @AralRoca tried on IOS Chrome, it works. I am on IOS 15.3.1

Answer (score 25):

This bookmarklet creator will come in handy to squish your JavaScript into one line: http://mrcoles.com/bookmarklet/

Comment: That one choked on my complicated function, but the idea of searching up a generator to build it for you is a good one.

Answer (score 11):

Here is an example of one that lets you edit the webpage like a document.

```
javascript:document.body.contentEditable = 'true'; document.designMode='on'; void 0
```

Comment: The most awesome answer that I have ever seined

Comment: Is it work in Chrome mobile?

Comment: It works on mobile as well. Look at this guide: https://www.labnol.org/software/google-chrome-bookmarklets/27894/ or https://paul.kinlan.me/use-bookmarklets-on-chrome-on-android/

Answer (score 4):

```
javascript : { document.getElementById('PlateNo').value='0815';document.getElementById('AppRef').value='013007';document.getElementById('VehicleReg').value='MX53 YMD'; void(0) }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use prompts and alerts and confirm windows, and I created a game, kind of. It's not that clean though. Here's the javascript-code:

To the editor: there needs to be a "javascript:" at the start for it to work btw

```
javascript: 
var totalClicks = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){
    var message1 = prompt("Clicker Game!\nClicks: "+totalClicks,"remove this text to end the game");
    totalClicks++;
    if (message1 !== "remove this text to end the game"){
        i = Math.Infinity;
    }
}
alert("Thanks for playing my game!\nClicks: "+totalClicks)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Mozilla use like as

```
javascript:function myFun(){
var d=document;
var e=d.getElementById("someElement");
var e.value="some value";
}myFun();
```