# How to bookmark page when click submit button o a webpage (Opera Extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, opera

i'm trying to write an Opera extension. I need to add a page to favourites when user click submit button.
For example there is a web page:

```
<html>
....
  <input id="button-submit" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="doSomething();">
...
</html>
```

and i want to make an extension that provides additional action (create bookmark) when user click submit. I wrote something, but it doesn't work:

```
var button = document.getElementById('button-submit');
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
chrome.bookmarks.create({'parentId': 1,
                         'title': 'My extension'});
});
```

Please help :)

Comment: Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872679/function-as-google-chrome-bookmark

Comment: chrome.bookmarks API [isn't available](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) in a content script. Send a message to your background/event page script which has access to this API (provided it's added in your manifest.json "permissions").

Comment: thanks @wOxxOm, i'll try this :)