# Script running from Console but printing variables from Bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, chromium, bookmarklet

I love to pimp my *Chrome/Chromium* experience with [JavaScript/Bookmarklets](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Bookmarklets), but now i am facing the following problem:

### The code

```
javascript:/*img2float*/ var str=prompt("src of img to float",document.querySelector("img").getAttribute('src'));str.length>0?content=str:content="Alap/Alap00.gif",document.querySelector("img[src*='"+content+"']").style.cssText="position:fixed;left:0;top:0;max-height:200px;box-shadow: 1px 1px 46px -21px;opacity:0.9";
```

### Explained

1. `var src=prompt("src of <img> to float",document.querySelector("img").getAttribute('src'));` *src* **attribute** of first *<img>*
2. `scr.length>0?` **if** *NOT NULL*
3. `var ThisDOM=src:`
   *ThisDOM* = *prompted value*, **else**
4. `ThisDOM="Alap/Alap00.gif",` **default**, most used settings
5. `document.querySelector("img[src*='"+ThisDOM+"']").` **select** the desired *<img>*
6. `style.cssText=` add desired **css style**
7. `"position:fixed;left:0;top:0;max-height:200px;box-shadow: 1px 1px 46px -21px;opacity:0.9";` css style **settings**

### The problem

- [✔] Running the code from *DevTools>Console* apply the css style settings to the image properly,
- [**ø**] but running from the *Bookmarklet* just printing out the *css style **settings*** (Explained at 7.)

Answer (score 0):

During the process of beautifying my question above i tried wrapping the code in a function as described here: [javascript - function as google chrome bookmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872679/function-as-google-chrome-bookmark#18872722) and finally did work!

### The wrapper

```
javascript:(function(){ })();
```

### Final code

```
javascript:/*img2float*/ (function(){var scr=prompt("src of img to float",document.querySelector("img").getAttribute('src'));scr.length>0?ThisDOM=scr:ThisDOM="Alap/Alap00.gif",document.querySelector("img[src*='"+ThisDOM+"']").style.cssText="position:fixed;left:0;top:0;max-height:200px;box-shadow: 1px 1px 46px -21px;opacity:0.9";})();
```

**But i am still curious why didn't work without the function wrapper?**