# is it possible to import javascript libraries to browser console(devtools)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, devtools

im writing my own javascript library at the moment and want to permanently import it to the microsoft edge devtools console (or devtools in general), to use it there,but i dont know how to import it

thanks in advance,
-Gzrespect

Comment: do you have localhost? then just `await import('http://localhost:1234/file.js')`

Comment: whats the file path then? cuz i have the lib a few folders deep in my system
also i want it to stay imported permanently,not import it again everytime i use the console

Comment: You will probably have to build & bundle the library (in a single file). Then, maybe you can look at building a wrapper browser extension, which wraps your library and provides global object[s] to play around with your lib.

Comment: Depending on _library_ you can just create Bookmarklet that will execute JS code on bookmark click

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function as Google Chrome bookmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872679/function-as-google-chrome-bookmark)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you don't have a local server, get one at https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb/ and set up a folder to serve.
2. set CORS in advanced server settings to allow importing it on most websites
3. use `let myModule = await import('http://127.0.0.1:8887/myModule.ts')` to import it

---

note: that should be ES module (with imports if there are multimple files) and not CJS module (with requires)

Comment: is it possible to either automatically import it on devtools start or have it permanently imported?

Comment: @Gzrespect You may use userscript extension to import it specific websites, like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-javascript-and-css/nbhcbdghjpllgmfilhnhkllmkecfmpld or Tampermonkey