# Can I run JavaScript from a mobile bookmark

Tags: javascript, mobile, bookmarks

I know basically nothing about how to run JavaScript or how it is supposed to work in a bookmark. I just see pages on how it is supposed to work and I can't figure it out!!1

Can I run JavaScript from a bookmark on a phone?
I am using an Android and the chrome app. I edit my bookmark and put examples that I have found online and I don't see it doing anything.

If it is possible, can someone ***post something that I can literally copy/paste into the bookmark*** for chrome and see it do something like say `hello world`?

I have tried `javascript:(alert("hello world");)` and `javascript:(function(){alert("hello world");})`

I looked at these links and couldn't figure it out:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18872722/5582694

What am I doing wrong???

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/232566

Comment: I tired `javascript:alert('foo');` and didn't see anything. What am I supposed to see or is that a valid example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought we can not use bookmarklets on mobile but after this question, I did a small research and here is the result:

We can set up a bookmarklet on Chrome and then use it on our phone This is the way we can do it:

On your desktop browser, right-click on the bookmarks bar and select "Add Page" or "Add Bookmark" from the menu.
In the "Name" field, enter a name for your bookmarklet.
In the "URL" field, enter the following code:

```
javascript:(function() { 
    alert("This is my test bookmarklet")
 })();
```

(This is just a test code and within the function, you can write your own code)

Now in the mobile browser, open up a page, and then within that page type your bookmarklet name(It has a star beside it) and then click it to see the alert test.
Here's the result on desktop and mobile:
[image]

[image]

Comment: What alternatives do you think there are?

Comment: Oh, wait, I found a solution for it.
I edited the original answer so you can use the solution and modify the code the way you want.

Comment: What is the function/bookmark supposed to do? I don't see anything on the computer or phone.

Comment: It must show an alert when you are on a page and click on the book mark that you created. I edited the answer and shared a screen shot of the result.

Comment: Oh, ok, on my computer, I had to be on a page for the bookmark to show the alert. I still don't see anything on the phone.

Comment: Now I added a picture from my phone too, I hope it helps.

Comment: How do you get that window on the left side of the bottom screen shot?

Comment: Oh, I see now. I am not exactly sure what I was doing wrong before. I guess I was just hitting enter on my phone instead of scrolling down and tapping the starred bookmark in the auto populated results.